# How do Jehovah's Witnesses understand Galatians 1:11-12?

Tags: exegesis, christology, jehovahs-witnesses, galatians

The Apostle Paul stated at Galatians 1:11-12 the following:

> Galatians 1:11-12: For I would have you know, brethern, that the gospel which was preached by me is **not according to man**. For **I neither received it from man**, nor was I taught it, but I received it through a revelation of Jesus Christ.

Also, Galatians 1:1:

> Paul an apostle  (not sent from men, nor through the agency of man, but through Jesus Christ, and God the Father, who raised Him from the dead.

Then there is one more verse declaring the gospel of Jesus Christ at Mark 1:1:

> The beginning of the gospel of Jesus Christ, the Son of God.

So Paul is informing us that the origin of the gospel he shared with them/the Galatians went back directly to a revelation of Jesus Christ Himself. It is the book of Acts that records what happened to Paul at Acts 9:3-19.

So the question is how Jehovah's Witnesses, who teach that Jesus Christ was only a human man and not God, reconcile the Apostle Paul saying he did not receive the gospel from any man nor did any man teach him the
gospel?

Comment: JWs do not teach that “Jesus was only a human man”.    They also do not teach that Jesus was/is just another angel.  Otherwise your question is ok.

Comment: Mr bond you should asked separate questions to address things you wish to say in response to an answer, not edit the original question

Answer (score 2):

To find the Jehovah's Witness perspective, I looked at their *“Insight On The Scriptures”* book, vol. 1. The first indication is that they have no subject heading, “Gospel”. They seem to avoid that word, replacing it with “the good news” instead. Their *New World Translation* of those verses you ask about read,

> “For I put you on notice, brothers, that the good news which was
> declared by me as good news is not something human; for neither did I
> receive it from man, nor was I taught [it], except through revelation
> by Jesus Christ.”

So, under the heading “Good News” I looked for anything about Jesus no longer being a man after his resurrection and found nothing, as they do not link those verses with your points at all.  A JW answer has already stated,

> “after he was resurrected, he was a mighty spirit creature. The
> Apostle Paul received his gospel after Jesus was resurrected, so Jesus
> was no longer a man then.”

That was followed with four texts from their NWT to support that claim, one having a mistranslation of the Greek, but that is not the point of this question, nor of my answer. The JW answer agrees with my point that JWs do not see in Galatians 1:12-13 any problem with their doctrine of the resurrected Christ no longer being human.

Next, I looked at the subject heading “Resurrection”, which takes nine pages, but did not find Galatians 1:12-13 mentioned, which is not surprising as it has no bearing on the subject in general or on whether Christ was raised with a glorified physical body, or an immaterial spirit body.  There is, however a paragraph claiming that at Jesus’ resurrection he

> “was granted immortality and incorruption, which no creature in the
> flesh can have…” Then, when dealing with the resurrection of Christ’s
> brothers, it claims that “They must die a death like Christ’s –
> maintaining integrity and giving up human life forever… Christ’s
> faithful brothers, who join him in the heavens, give up human life.
> The apostle Paul shows that they have to have new bodies…”

I quote these bits because they underline the JW doctrine of those going to heaven having to “give up” their physical bodies and that new bodies are created for them for “the soul, the person that is resurrected” to then inhabit in heaven. That is their teaching, which they apply equally to Jesus Christ as to those who are to be with him in heaven.

It would appear that you have raised some points about Galatians 1:12-13 that they have never considered before, but from what they do believe, they would just take those verses as harmonising with their doctrine of physical bodies having to be “given up” before a new spirit body would be created for those going to live in heaven. They insist that a new spirit body had to be made for the resurrected Jesus. The body he died in, and which was laid in the tomb, was never seen again by anyone, including Jesus, who found himself in a new, spirit body, that he could (at will) change to appear to be fleshly, though it was not. Page 786 of the JW *‘Insight’* book, vol. 1, makes that clear. Therefore, you are coming at those verses from a totally different angle to how the JWs view them, and your points will either be misunderstood by them, or dismissed by them as irrelevant, for your approach is incompatible with theirs and *vice versa*.

Comment: Referencing comments you made on another answer is not ideal since comments are frequently purged.   The last part of your answer would be more appropriate in a chat with mr bond than in in the answer space.

Comment: As I believe I have purged this comment thread, I think it might be worth it to edit your answer a bit.  Ideally answers are self-contained and not referencing other content on the site (makes it too forum like and not Q&A like)

Comment: @ Peter Turner  That reference removed, as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Jehovah's Witnesses believe that Jesus was a man during his time on earth, but not just any ordinary man. He was the Christ, he was God's Son, and he was perfect. What Jesus taught was not of his own originality but was from God, his Father. **(John 8:28; John 14:10)**

Before Jesus came to earth and after he was resurrected, he was a mighty spirit creature. The Apostle Paul received his gospel after Jesus was resurrected, so Jesus was no longer a man then.

> **1 Peter 3:18 (NWT)**
> For Christ died once for all time for sins, a righteous person for unrighteous ones, in order to lead you to God. **He was put to death in the flesh but made alive in the spirit.**

> **Acts 13:34 (NWT)**
> And the fact that **He resurrected him from the dead never again to return to corruption**, He has stated in this way: ‘I will give you the expressions of loyal love promised to David, which are faithful.’

> **1 Corinthians 15:45 (NWT)**
> So it is written: “The first man Adam became a living person.” **The last Adam became a life-giving spirit.**

> **2 Corinthians 5:16 (NWT)**
> So from now on we know no man from a fleshly viewpoint. **Even if we once knew Christ according to the flesh, we certainly no longer know him in that way.**

**Sources:**
jw.org > Bible Questions Answered > [After Jesus’ Resurrection, Was His Body Flesh or Spirit?](https://www.jw.org/finder?wtlocale=E&docid=502015203&srcid=share)
*What Can the Bible Teach Us?* > [Chapter 4: "Who Is Jesus Christ?"](https://www.jw.org/finder?wtlocale=E&docid=1102015144&srcid=share)